# How to release pagination in "GET" search?

Tags: php, pagination

I use this code For search in database:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['keywords'])) {

        $keywords = $CONNECT->escape_string($_GET['keywords']);
        if(!$keywords){
            echo("<script>location.href = '/news';</script>"); 

            //if javascript disabled
            $url='/news';
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; '.$url.'">';
        }
        $Query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `id`, `title`, `himg`, `readed` FROM `news`  WHERE `content` LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR `title` LIKE '%{$keywords}%'");
    ?>         
            <div class="found">founded<?php echo $Query->num_rows; ?> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="ncontent"> 
     <div class="keyword">phrase: "<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($keywords); ?></p>"</div>
    <?php
    if($Query->num_rows){
      while ($r =  $Query->fetch_object()){
    ?>
       <div class="nline"><a href="/news/content/id/<?php echo $r->id; ?>"><div class="prewnews">
                    <div class="imgh1"><img src="<?php echo $r->himg; ?>"/></div>
                    <span><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"> <p>124</p></i><hr style="background:#cd4436; border:0; height:3px" /><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"> <p><?php echo $r->readed; ?></p></i> </span>
                    <h3><?php echo $r->title; ?></h3>
                </div>
              </a>
              </div>   
    <?php   
           }
         }else echo '<div class="notfound"><img src="/resource/img/notfound.png" alt=""></div>';
       }else {echo("<script>location.href = '/news';</script>"); 
              $url='/news';
              echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; '.$url.'">';}
    ?>
```

---

Search form:

---

```
         <form action="/search" method="GET">
            <input class="search red" placeholder="search..." type="search" name="keywords" autocomplete="off">
         </form>
```

---

So, after search i get link like this: `/search?keywords=test+search+phrase`
As I think i can do like this: `/search?keywords=test+search+phrase&page2`
or like this: `/page2/search?keywords=test+search+phrase`

---

What you advise, which way pagination?
And can you provide links that will help to realize them?
Or anyone of you can help me here?

Comment: why not `page=2`? then it's a simple matter of doing `$_GET['page']`. With `page2`, you'd have to scan the ENTIRE query string to try and figure out where is `pageX` and extract the `X` component.

Comment: My solution is based on what @MarcB said ^ i.e `...&page=123`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following **pagination solution** will show at most 10 search results per page, and for navigating rest of the search results, use pagination links. The solution will show at most 5 links per page, kind of like this:

```
// user is on 1st page
1 2 3 4 5 ...
-

// user is on 7th page
... 5 6 7 8 9 ...
        -

// user is on 10th page(lets say, 10th page is the last page)
... 6 7 8 9 10
             -
```

So, to implement this pagination functionality, you need to make few changes in your code. Keep your **HTML** search form as it is, and change your **PHP** code in the following way,

- First check if there's any `...&page=123` exists or not in the URL, and based on that, process your `$_GET` superglobal like this way,

  ```
  if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])){
      $current_page = $_GET['page'];
  }else{
      $current_page = 1;
  }
  ```
- Define rows per page and calculate offset based on that, like this:

  ```
  $per_page = 10;  // rows per page
  $offset = ($current_page - 1) * $per_page;  // offset
  ```
- And fetch table results based on these `$per_page` and `$offset` values, like this:

  ```
  $Query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT ...  WHERE `content` LIKE ... LIMIT ". $per_page . " OFFSET " . $offset);
  ```

Now to display pagination links below the search results, follow the below procedure:

- Get total number of rows from the queried result set and calculate total number of page/pagination links to display, like this:

  ```
  // display pagination links
  $Query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT ... FROM `news`  WHERE `content` LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR `title` LIKE '%{$keywords}%'");
  if($Query->num_rows){
      $total_records = $Query->num_rows;
      $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

      ...
  ```
- Find the superset range of pages, like 1-10, or 1-20 etc. For example, if `$total_pages = 20` then this superset range would be 1-20. The code for this step is this:

  ```
  // superset range of pages
  $superset_range = range(1, $total_pages);
  ```
- Find the subset range of pages to display, like 1-5, or 3-7 etc. For example, if `$total_pages = 20` then this subset range would be 1-5, or 3-7, or 6-10 etc., it can be any consecutive five pages between 1 and 20. Also, adjust this range whenever necessary. The code for this step is this:

  ```
  // subset range of pages to display
  $subset_range = range($current_page - 2, $current_page + 2);

  // adjust the range(if required)
  foreach($subset_range as $p){
      if($p < 1){
          array_shift($subset_range);
          if(in_array($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1, $superset_range)){
              $subset_range[] = $subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1;
          }
      }elseif($p > $total_pages){
          array_pop($subset_range);
          if(in_array($subset_range[0] - 1, $superset_range)){
              array_unshift($subset_range, $subset_range[0] - 1);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally, display the pagination links and dots accordingly. The code for this step is this:

  ```
  // display intermediate pagination links
  if($subset_range[0] > $superset_range[0]){
      echo "...&nbsp;";
  }
  foreach($subset_range as $p){
      if($p == $current_page){
          echo "<a href='/search?keywords=" . $keywords . "&page=" . $p . "' style='text-decoration: underline;'>$p</a>";
      }else{
          echo "<a href='/search?keywords=" . $keywords . "&page=" . $p . "'>$p</a>";
      }

  }
  if($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] < $superset_range[count($superset_range) - 1]){
      echo "&nbsp;... ";
  }
  ```

Here's **the complete code**:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['keywords'])) {

        $keywords = $CONNECT->escape_string($_GET['keywords']);
        if(!$keywords){
            echo("<script>location.href = '/news';</script>"); 

            //if javascript disabled
            $url='/news';
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; '.$url.'">';
        }
        if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])){
            $current_page = $_GET['page'];
        }else{
            $current_page = 1;
        }
        $per_page = 10;
        $offset = ($current_page - 1) * $per_page;
        $Query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `id`, `title`, `himg`, `readed` FROM `news`  WHERE `content` LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR `title` LIKE '%{$keywords}%' LIMIT ". $per_page . " OFFSET " . $offset);
        ?>         
                <div class="found">founded<?php echo $Query->num_rows; ?> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ncontent"> 
        <div class="keyword">phrase: "<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($keywords); ?></p>"</div>
        <?php
        if($Query->num_rows){
            while ($r =  $Query->fetch_object()){
        ?>
            <div class="nline">
                <a href="/news/content/id/<?php echo $r->id; ?>">
                    <div class="prewnews">
                        <div class="imgh1">
                            <img src="<?php echo $r->himg; ?>"/>
                        </div>
                        <span>
                            <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"> 
                                <p>124</p>
                            </i>
                            <hr style="background:#cd4436; border:0; height:3px" />
                            <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"> 
                                <p><?php echo $r->readed; ?></p>
                            </i> 
                        </span>
                        <h3><?php echo $r->title; ?></h3>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>   
        <?php   
            }

            // display pagination links
            $Query = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `id`, `title`, `himg`, `readed` FROM `news`  WHERE `content` LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR `title` LIKE '%{$keywords}%'");
            if($Query->num_rows){
                $total_records = $Query->num_rows;
                $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

                if($total_records > $per_page){
                    echo "<center>";

                    // Superset range of pages
                    $superset_range = range(1, $total_pages);

                    // subset range of pages to display
                    $subset_range = range($current_page - 2, $current_page + 2);

                    // adjust the range(if required)
                    foreach($subset_range as $p){
                        if($p < 1){
                            array_shift($subset_range);
                            if(in_array($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1, $superset_range)){
                                $subset_range[] = $subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1;
                            }
                        }elseif($p > $total_pages){
                            array_pop($subset_range);
                            if(in_array($subset_range[0] - 1, $superset_range)){
                                array_unshift($subset_range, $subset_range[0] - 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // display intermediate pagination links
                    if($subset_range[0] > $superset_range[0]){
                        echo "...&nbsp;";
                    }
                    foreach($subset_range as $p){
                        if($p == $current_page){
                            echo "<a href='/search?keywords=" . $keywords . "&page=" . $p . "' style='text-decoration: underline;'>$p</a>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<a href='/search?keywords=" . $keywords . "&page=" . $p . "'>$p</a>";
                        }

                    }
                    if($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] < $superset_range[count($superset_range) - 1]){
                        echo "&nbsp;... ";
                    }

                    echo "</center> ";  
                }    
            }

        }else{
            echo '<div class="notfound"><img src="/resource/img/notfound.png" alt=""></div>';
        }
    }else {
        echo("<script>location.href = '/news';</script>"); 
        $url='/news';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; '.$url.'">';
    }
?>
```